# Not able to mock private methods using POWERMOCK and mockito

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin, mockito, powermock

even when I am using the spy method, I am not able to mock the getContext() method of attributesStorage() to get my context.
this is my code :

```
class Rich
{
    fun method1() : HashMap<String,String>  
    {
        val x = attributeStorage().getStore()
        return x
    }

}

class AttributeStorage
{

    private fun getContext()
    {
        return MyProject.instance.context() 
    }

    fun getStore()
    {
        //some work done,   
        return HashMap<String,String>()
    }
}

@PrepareForTest(Rich::class)
class RichTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var mcontext: Context


 fun init()
    {
        mcontext = Mockito.mock(Context::class.java)
        val mAttributesStorage = spy(AttributesStorage())
        `when`<Context>(mAttributesStorage,"getContext").thenReturn(mcontext)
        Mockito.`when`(mAttributesStorage.getStore()).thenReturn(mapOf("1" to "1"))

    }
 fun test()
 {
     //gives an error because the getContext() couldn't be mocked
 }

}
```

I looked at every question possible on stack overflow and went through powermock and mockito documentation but couldn't find a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
@Mock
lateinit var mcontext: Context
```

and

```kotlin
mcontext = Mockito.mock(Context::class.java)
```

are one too many. Use either the one or the other (annotation preferred, of course).

See [Shorthand for mocks creation - @Mock annotation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock_annotation):

> **Important!** This needs to be somewhere in the base class or a test runner:
>
> `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(testClass);`

Regarding your last code comment: objects are *mocked*, methods are *stubbed*.

Comment: Hey
It still doesn't solve my the error I am getting
"lateint properly context hasen't been initialized"

Comment: @coder Is your `init()` method executed or isn't the [`@Before`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/Before.html) annotation missing? The `test()` method runs  without a [`@Test`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/Test.html) annotation since this is a relict from Junit <4: methods the name of which start with `test` are executed as tests.

Comment: yes my init is getting executed! and I have put the annotations as well!